# Adding an official oEmbed provider to Wordpress

Tags: embed, oembed

How can I add an official oEmbed provider to this list: https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds ?

Comment: Have you read [`wp_oembed_add_provider`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider)?

Comment: I was thinking about the cases where someone is using a hosted Wordpress service, and don't necessarily have access to this configuration.

Comment: If they have the ability to edit a theme's `functions.php` they'll be fine. Otherwise they'll more than likely have to work through their hosting provider to use the official hook.